# Why we can use fundamental solution as the kernel function in PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading Martinsson's book "Fast direct solvers for elliptic PDEs" (see https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611976045). In chapter 2, the explict solution of the problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u(x) & = 0,\quad x \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3, \\
u(x) & = g(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
is
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} F(x, y) g(y) \mathrm{d} s(y),$$
where
$$F(x, y) = - \frac{\partial G}{\partial n_y}(x, y)$$
and $G$ is the Green's function with respect to the bounded domain $\Omega$. However, since we always doesn't know the formula of $G$) (hence $F$), the author suggests to pursue a solution of the form
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \Gamma(x - y) \sigma(y) \mathrm{d} s(y)$$
where
$$\Gamma(x) = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{1}{|x|}$$
is the fundamental solution.

My question is, why we can give a solution of this form? For example, let $\Omega = B = \{x = (x_1, x_2, x_3): |x| < 1\}$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We know that the $F$ in the integral is
$$F(x, y) = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{1 - |x|^2}{|x-y|^3}, x \in B, y \in \partial B$$ So if the solution has the form
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \Gamma(x - y) \sigma(y) \mathrm{d} s(y),$$
there must be
$$F(x, y) g(y) = \Gamma(x - y) \sigma(y),$$
leading to
$$\sigma(y) = \frac{1 - |x|^2}{|x-y|^2} g(y),$$
which is a contradiction! Besides, it seems that the $\sigma$ item must have some singularity.

Can anyone explain why we can take fundamental solution in the kernel? Any contribution is appreciated

Comment: Should be $F(x,y) = (x_3 - y_3)/(2\pi|x-y|^3)$ I believe.

Comment: @eyeballfrog The Green's function of $H$ is $\Gamma(x - y) - \Gamma(x - \bar{y})$ where $\bar{y} = (y_1, y_2, -y_3)$

Comment: The similarity between the fundamental solution and the Green's function is known as [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle).

Comment: @K.defaoite Could you please explain the $H$ example? What can we say about $\sigma$? Or, is there any theoretical proof of the existence of $\sigma$ on a general bounded doman $\Omega$?

Comment: @JingyuLiu In that case, shouldn't we have $F(x,y) =- \partial_{y_3} H = (4\pi)^{-1} [(y_3 - x_3)/|x - y|^3 - (y_3 + x_3)/|x - \bar{y}|^3]$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Note that $n_y = (0, 0, -1)$, so $F(x, y) = (4 \pi)^{-1}[(x_3 - y_3 )/ |x - y|^3 + (x_3 + y_3) / |x - \bar{y}|^3]$. And since when $y \in \partial H$, $y = \bar{y}$, so we have the formular F mentioned in my description.

Comment: Oh, right, keep forgetting this is a surface integral not a volume integral. my mistake.

Comment: Be careful, your half space is not a bounded domain.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks for your comment. I have changed my example above. But it seems still a contradiction...

Comment: I'm sorry what is $g$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite There is a typo in my description. I have corrected it. $f$ ($g$) is the boundary value of $u$

Comment: Can you explain how the final line is a contradiction?